# Terminal not cleaning lines

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, vim, tmux

I'm working on a remote Ubuntu 20.10 machine [`linux version 5.8.0-1011-gcp`] in Google Cloud, built from a basic Ubuntu image, using `gnu bash 5.0.17(1)-release` and `xterm 353`, and the terminal isn't clearing lines:

- I've tried with an empty `.bashrc`, as well as the default upon user creation:

  - `$TERM` values:

    ```bash
    local (no tmux) - xterm-color
    local (   tmux) - screen-256color

    local (no tmux) - remote (no tmux) - xterm-color
    local (no tmux) - remote (   tmux) - screen

    local (   tmux) - remote (no tmux) - screen-256color
    local (   tmux) - remote (   tmux) - screen
    ```
  - Terminal output:

    ```bash
    # Before pressing Enter and typing "dog":
      cd dir_cat
      cd dir_2
      reset

    # After pressing Enter and typing "dog":
      dogdir_cat
      cd dir_2
      reset

    # Expected behavior after pressing Enter and typing "dog":
      dog
    ```

If I use `tmux`, I still get the same behavior, albeit less problematic than when I don't use it, however `vim` has the same issue; as such, I would fundamentally infer `screen` has the issue too

- **`tmux`:** 
   When I use `tmux`, I do so after logging into the remote, and am not using `tmux` on local machine.

  - If I log into the remote and immediately start `tmux`, both in-shell and when using `vim`, I am not affected by the issue; however, if I open `vim` outside of `tmux`, then `tmux` starts experiencing the issue *(normal shell and when using `vim` within it)*
- **`vim`:** 
   Scrolling in `vim` also shows issues like the above, but I assume if `clear`/`reset` are fixed, then this possibly gets fixed too

  - I've tried getting rid of `.vimrc`, but it changed nothing
- **`Clear`, `reset`, `printf '\[e[`:** 
   These and all other workarounds found via a Google search do not work, with the issue not being limited to `clear`/`reset`, so please do not provide workarounds for `clear`/`reset`, as I need to fix the underlying issue

Comment: Have you checked the terminal config database (`termcap` or similar), as that's what controls the terminal type selected (e.g.`xterm`, `xterm-256color`, `screen-256color`, etc. with `xterm-256color` generally being the one to use)

Comment: I didn't even know terminfo was a thing. Still, while I've read a bit and while I still have no clue on why and how the issue happens, I understood that I can pick a different terminal by setting `TERM`, so, since `xterm-256color` is affected too, I set it to `screen` which is the only one working correctly. I assume it's going to be fine since it's what tmux uses anyway.

Comment: Ubuntu uses a different terminal config database config, however I forget which one, as it's not `termcap` by default. The issue likely resides within whatever one Ubuntu uses, as it's that config that controls clearing of content from the terminal or whether content remains after execution. It very well could be something else, but either that or the config for `tmux`  seems the most likely.